# Windows (Vista): Set process-priority on a program shortcut

Tags: windows, performance, itunes

Is there any way to launch a program with a shortcut, that sets the process-priority of that program?

iTunes is dragging my system to it's knees, but when I set the process-priority to "low", somehow, like magic, Windows gets back to it's normal responsive self :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You learn something new every day.

My answer was wrong, but since it was marked accepted I'm editing to be right.

Change your short cut to point to:

```
start /BELOWNORMAL iTunes.exe
```

Instead of just iTunes.exe

Comment: Just realized that this was not a programming question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: But this answer is incorrect!  Change the icon shortcut to call "start /BELOWNORMAL itunes.exe" instead of itunes.exe and you are all set!

Comment: Very helpful. glad you asked/answered. Next time i have that program i wrote that runs doggedly i will start with this ;)

Comment: Thank you Mike! And nice of you to re-visit this question and update it, Joel.